# speaker not working no sound

Tags: sound

purchased a new dell inspiron 3542 with ubuntu OS. speaker not working. I am unable get any sound in the laptop. Contacted Dell, they said hardware is OK, issue with ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally better to remove the factory installed version of ubuntu and make a clean install yourself. If you can start ubuntu on your Inspiron laptop, then just create a bootable USB pen-drive as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692056/how-to-make-bootable-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-usb-in-debian-8-1/692543#692543) for 14.04 LTS. After that, you can boot your laptop with your pen-drive and make a clean install from there.