# How to make bootable Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on USB in Debian 8.1?

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, usb

I have Debian 8.1 in my system now and the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as ISO image. 
I know these pieces of advices for OSX [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) about making bootable usb in OSX.

### Pseudo unsuccessful solution

I did not manage to install unetbootin in Debian 8.1. 
Also, copying byte-wisely did not work. 
I made Windows 10 disk and opened the .iso image there. 
This way, I managed to install Ubuntu 14.04 but it required also ruining the Windows 10 installation; meaning two times work, since using other system to start the system. 
However, it is frustrating that I could not create easily Ubuntu USB where the system would boot.

I get now this after an unsuccessful try

[image]

There has to really be better options installing Ubuntu 14.04.

### Solution which works

Reject USB and burn the image to DVD. 
However, this is not an answer to the question.

---

How can you make a bootable USB of Ubuntu 14.04 in Debian 8.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For absolute newbies:

- Insert USB drive in your laptop running any linux distro.
- Its recommended to unmount the drive before writing, in case your file-manager has auto-mounted it.
- run `fdisk -l` as superuser and know the alias of your usb drive (`sdb`, `sdc`, etc.)
- run the command: `dd if=/path/to/downloaded/iso of=/dev/sdx` as superuser (replace `sdx` with your own device alias).
- Boot with the new usb drive.

Be careful with the `dd` command! Many people have lost their data with that one.

Comment: Thanks, the iso should be copied to `/dev/sdb` and not `/dev/sdb1`, your answer helped me figure that out.

Comment: Also [debian instructions](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s03.html.en) recommends unmounting the USB drive first with `sudo umount /dev/sdb1`.

Comment: Yes, its a good practice to unmount it before writing the new ISO.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure the step is mentioned in that link:

`sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/sdX bs=1m`

Where `/dev/sdX/` is the `/dev/` path to the disk you are writing to.

Comment: This method does not work. I also changed .iso to .img unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 2):

To create a live usb of any linux distro download unetbootin form here:

http://unetbootin.github.io/

Download the distro with unetbootin or download an iso from the homepage of the distro. You already downloaded ubuntu 14.04 so you can use that.

Follow the instructions in the link and create the live usb.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Prahlad Yeri's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/692543/315347) and 
the Debian GNU/Linux Installation Guide
[instructions on how to copy the iso image to a usb key](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s03.html.en).

1. Insert a USB key in your computer.
2. Find the device name

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   # An example of device name might be `/dev/sdb1`.
   ```
3. Unmount the USB key.

   ```
   sudo umount /dev/sdb1
   ```
4. Transfer the iso image to the key

   ```
   sudo cp debian-live-9.5.0-amd64-gnome.iso /dev/sdb
   # The iso should be copied to `sdb` and not to `sdb1` !
   ```
5. Restart the computer

To boot in your USB key, you might have to change the BIOS setup, and change some options such as enabling legacy boot, and disabling secure boot.